# Java Servlet. HTTP Status 404

Tags: java-ee, jsp, maven, servlet, tomcat

Не могу разобраться почему после запуска сервлета на Tomcat имею 404 ошибку? Суть в том, что до этого сервлет был работоспособен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
конфигурация Tomcat:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
вот сам web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>liga</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ui.BookServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>liga</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/liga</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>team</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ui.TeamServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>team</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/team</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>FirstServlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
  <title>SomePage</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello!
</body>
</html>
```

мой сервлет:

```
package ui;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BookServlet extends HttpServlet{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
       resp.getWriter().print("<h1>League of champions</h1>");
       resp.sendRedirect("/books.jsp");
    }
}
```

Вот логи:

```
"C:\Program Files\ForJava\apache-tomcat-7.0.85\bin\catalina.bat" run
[2018-04-17 01:51:26,080] Artifact FirstServlet:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Username\.IntelliJIdea2017.3\system\tomcat\Tomcat_7_0_85_FirstServlet"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\ForJava\apache-tomcat-7.0.85"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\ForJava\apache-tomcat-7.0.85\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\ForJava\apache-tomcat-7.0.85\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\ForJava\apache-tomcat-7.0.85\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:27 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.85
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Feb 7 2018 18:52:33 UTC
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.85.0
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           9.0.4+11
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Username\.IntelliJIdea2017.3\system\tomcat\Tomcat_7_0_85_FirstServlet
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\ForJava\apache-tomcat-7.0.85
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Username\.IntelliJIdea2017.3\system\tomcat\Tomcat_7_0_85_FirstServlet\conf\logging.properties
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Username\.IntelliJIdea2017.3\system\tomcat\Tomcat_7_0_85_FirstServlet
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\ForJava\apache-tomcat-7.0.85
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\ForJava\apache-tomcat-7.0.85\temp
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.16 using APR version 1.6.3.
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:28 ДП org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2m  2 Nov 2017)
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:29 ДП org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:29 ДП org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:29 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1823 ms
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:29 ДП org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:29 ДП org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.85
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:29 ДП org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:29 ДП org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:29 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 229 ms
Connected to server
[2018-04-17 01:51:29,873] Artifact FirstServlet:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:30 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:30 ДП org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [141] milliseconds.
[2018-04-17 01:51:30,952] Artifact FirstServlet:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2018-04-17 01:51:30,952] Artifact FirstServlet:war exploded: Deploy took 1 079 milliseconds
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:39 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\ForJava\apache-tomcat-7.0.85\webapps\manager
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:39 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
апр. 17, 2018 1:51:39 ДП org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\ForJava\apache-tomcat-7.0.85\webapps\manager has finished in 428 ms
```

Comment: Раз Солопов - скажу, что думаю по твоей проблеме. Твой прожект называется `FirstServlet`? Тогда в браузере надо открывать `http://localhost:8080/FirstServlet/`, а не так как у тебя написано `http://localhost:8080/`. Не 100-пудова конечно, я не знаю, что там может ideia нахимичить, но IDE без притязаний на inteliji поступают именно так. И ещё. У тебя же нет `books`. Есть `books.jsp`. И есть `liga`, которая отображается в `BookServlet`. Т.е. ни `http://localhost:8080/books`, ни `http://localhost:8080/FirstServlet/books` в принципе не существуют.

Comment: @Sergey Обычно при запуске проекта открывался localhost:8080 файл index.jsp. В данном случае- по любому из вышеперечисленных адресов выбивается 404 Error.

Comment: суть в том- что раньше работало и после какого-то этапа перестало. Или это от того, что подтянул зависимость <war> или случайно что-то изменил в конфигурациях сервера.
Дело даже не в этом коде, а в общем- потому что создавая новые  сервлеты- получаю ту же ситуацию.

Comment: в представленном `web.xml` нет ни мапинга `books` куда бы то ни было, ни конфигурации `welcome`-файлов (т. е. index.jsp не подставляется автоматом в адрес типа `http://localhost:8080/`